# Django: Hide required field in form and generate value from other fields

Tags: django

Having a class like this:

```
class MyClass():
    foo = CharField('Foo', max_length=42)
    bar = CharField('Bar', max_length=42)
    baz = CharField('Baz', max_length=42)
```

Fields "foo" and "bar" should be show in the form, field "baz" should NOT be shown.
When POST'ing, the field "baz" should be generated from "foo" and "bar", e.g.:

```
baz = foo + bar
```

The "baz" field can be prevented from shown in the form by using the "HiddenInput" widget. Ok.

But using the CBV: Where to generate the "baz" content from "foo" and "bar"? In the "def post()", in the "def is_valid()", in the "def clean()"? Or somewhere else?

Answer (score -1):

You should override the function is_valid() and update the baz value in it.
This is because, you will get the validated values.

```
def is_valid(self):
     valid = super(YourForm,self).is_valid()
     if valid:
          ##  do your stuff
```